# Executing SQL query in Java for which Sub query result is already fetched separately

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Is it possible to execute a SQL query in Java for which sub query result is already fetched

e.g. Suppose I have a query

```
SELECT A.NAME FROM (SELECT NAME, CLASS FROM ABC_TABLE) A WHERE A.CLASS = 1;
```

What I want is that if I execute the sub query separately i.e.,

```
SELECT NAME, CLASS FROM ABC_TABLE
```

and the result which I get from Result Set will get modified based on some Java calculations & then that modified result needs to be passed to the 1st main query.

Is it possible.

Note: The example given above is a sample. Actually sub query is very big of 300-400 lines & so is the main query

Comment: Select your subquery into temporary table, then retrieve and alter this data, and finally use it in main query. Or execute the subquery and retrieve/process data, save processed data into temporary table and use. *based on some Java calculations* Maybe this calculations may be performed by MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Use Alias to sort it out. Following is the query which I used and it is working:

```
Select * from (select * from 
              (select * from school.questionbank where class='class-II' 
               AND Subject='Physic') A 
               where chapter='chapter 1') B 
where isMCQ=1;
```

Note that A and B are temporary tables created in the memory by SQL